# Structuring php array to pass to google pie charts arrayToDataTable

Tags: javascript, php, google-visualization

Could someone please tell me how to structure my php array so that i can plug it straight into the Google pie chart API? Here is my current code:

PHP:

```
// class containing sql

$browser_data = browser_data();

// array to populate titles
$data_array['titles'] = array('title', 'amount');



 //array to populate data
    foreach($browser_data as $k=>$val) {
        $data_array[$k] = array($k, $val['examples']);
    }
```

JS:

```
data_array = <?=json_encode($data_array)?>;
   var data = google.visualization.arrayToDataTable(data_array);
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove `'titles'` and '$k' from the array keys, as `json_encode` will create an object from an associative array instead of an array.  This is what you need:

```
// array to populate titles
$data_array[] = array('title', 'amount');

// array to populate data
foreach($browser_data as $k=>$val) {
    $data_array[] = array($k, $val['examples']);
}
```

If your data source outputs numbers as strings (some databases, including MySQL, do this), you  need to add `JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK` to the `json_encode` call:

```
data_array = <?=json_encode($data_array, JSON_NUMERIC_CHECK)?>;
```